# doubly linked list: value is not inserted at front

Tags: c++, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

Here is a DLinkedList Implementation, an element of int type is added to it using addFront(), but its not retrieved using front().. No Error is displayed. Don't know why ?? Here is complete implementation. Code is run on xCode4.5.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    DLinkedList listOne;

    if(listOne.empty()){
        cout<<"Empty";
    }
    const int num=23;
    listOne.addFront(num);

    //Here 0 is returned from front(), while it should be 23;
    cout<<listOne.front()<<endl;

    return 0;
}

//Node Defination
class DNode {                   // doubly linked list node
private:
    int elem;                   // node element value
    DNode* prev;                // previous node in list
    DNode* next;                // next node in list
    friend class DLinkedList;           // allow DLinkedList access
};

class DLinkedList {             // doubly linked list
public:
    DLinkedList();              // constructor
    ~DLinkedList();             // destructor
    bool empty() const;             // is list empty?
    const int front() const;            // get front element
    const int back() const;         // get back element
    void addFront(const int e);     // add to front of list
    void addBack(const int e);      // add to back of list
    void removeFront();             // remove from front
    void removeBack();              // remove from back
private:                    // local type definitions
    DNode* header;              // list sentinels
    DNode* trailer;
protected:                  // local utilities
    void add(DNode* v, const int e);        // insert new node before v
    void remove(DNode* v);          // remove node v
};

void listReverse(DLinkedList& L) {      // reverse a list
    DLinkedList T;              // temporary list
    while (!L.empty()) {            // reverse L into T
        int s = L.front();  L.removeFront();
        T.addFront(s);
    }
    while (!T.empty()) {            // copy T back to L
        int s = T.front();  T.removeFront();
        L.addBack(s);
    }
}

void DLinkedList::remove(DNode* v) {        // remove node v
    DNode* u = v->prev;             // predecessor
    DNode* w = v->next;             // successor
    u->next = w;                // unlink v from list
    w->prev = u;
    delete v;
}

void DLinkedList::removeFront()     // remove from font
{ remove(header->next); }

void DLinkedList::removeBack()      // remove from back
{ remove(trailer->prev); }

// insert new node before v
void DLinkedList::add(DNode* v, const int e) {
    DNode* u = new DNode;  u->elem = e;     // create a new node for e
    std::cout<<u->elem<<std::endl;
    u->next = v;                // link u in between v
    u->prev = v->prev;              // ...and v->prev
    v->prev->next = v->prev = u;
}

void DLinkedList::addFront(const int e) // add to front of list
{
    add(header->next, e);
}

void DLinkedList::addBack(const int e)  // add to back of list
{ add(trailer, e); }

DLinkedList::~DLinkedList() {           // destructor
    while (!empty()) removeFront();     // remove all but sentinels
    delete header;              // remove the sentinels
    delete trailer;
}

DLinkedList::DLinkedList() {            // constructor
    header = new DNode;             // create sentinels
    trailer = new DNode;
    header->next = trailer;         // have them point to each other
    trailer->prev = header;
    std::cout<<"DLinkedListConstructor"<<std::endl;
}

bool DLinkedList::empty() const     // is list empty?
{ return (header->next == trailer); }

const int DLinkedList::front() const    // get front element
{ return header->next->elem; }

const int DLinkedList::back() const     // get back element
{ return trailer->prev->elem; }
```

Comment: Please preview your question before posting it next time. Also, including a question usually helps. Please produce an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I still can't see a question mark

Comment: @Zubair You just changed the title. The title is a brief description of your question. The body of your post should contain your question in detail (errors, what you expect, what you get, etc.) and an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Re: the code itself, you can make your life a lot easier by considering this: why do you use "sentinels" when the language provides you a perfectly fitting one already: **NULL**. I'd srsly consider just how much of this goes away if you manage empty-list state with NULL head an tail pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your `add` function:

```
// insert new node before v
void DLinkedList::add(DNode* v, const int e) {
    DNode* u = new DNode;  u->elem = e;     // create a new node for e
    std::cout<<u->elem<<std::endl;
    u->next = v;                // link u in between v
    u->prev = v->prev;              // ...and v->prev
    v->prev->next = v->prev = u;
}
```

Let's follow it through. You begin with the following situation (I've called the node that `v->prev` points to `p`):

```
┌───────────┐
│           ▼
p ◀──────── v

      u
```

You then set `u->next` to `v`:

```
┌───────────┐
│           ▼
p ◀──────── v
            ▲
      u─────┘
```

And then `u->prev` to `v->prev`:

```
┌───────────┐
│           ▼
p ◀──────── v
▲           ▲
└─────u─────┘
```

The next line is the problem. First it assigns `u` to `v->prev`:

```
┌───────────┐
│           ▼
p     ┌──── v
▲     ▼     ▲
└─────u─────┘
```

Then it assigns the same pointer to `v->prev->next`. But `v->prev` is now `u`, so you're just setting `u->next` to point at `v` and it already does. So there's no change.

Now when you attempt to get the front element, you are just getting element `v`, which is your sentinel node.

You need to do these two assignments separately:

```
v->prev->next = u;
v->prev = u;
```

Comment: Thanks @sftrabbit, you eleborated it very-Well.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are not initializing the `prev` and `next` pointers for *all* of your nodes. When you construct the list, your list's constructor does:

```
header = new DNode;             // create sentinels
trailer = new DNode;
header->next = trailer;         // have them point to each other
trailer->prev = header;
```

Which means `header->prev` and `trailer->next` are uninitialized. These pointers do not get initialized to `NULL` automatically, so beware.

But the root cause of what you observe is that in your `add_front()` function, you are invoking an `add()` function that ends up doing this:

```
// Replacing v with header->next, which is the actual argument of the call
...
u->next = header->next;          // u->next = trailer      
u->prev = header->next->prev;    // u->prev = trailer->prev; // Uninitialized!
header->next->prev = u;          // trailer->prev = u;
header->next->prev->next = u;    // u->next = u
```

Which is obviously wrong because of the last statement, and because you never assign `header->next = u`.

Btw, I suggest you considering the use of smart pointers instead of raw pointers, with the proper choice according to the desired ownership semantics. Among other things, smart pointers get automatically initialized to `nullptr`.

Answer (score 1):

The code ran just fine on Mingw Compiler in windows, and gave 23, not 0, using codeblocks....
However, I suggest making the following changes, since some compilers assign values from right to left, a stack thing....

```
void DLinkedList::add(DNode* v, const int e) {
    DNode* u = new DNode;  u->elem = e;     // create a new node for e
    std::cout<<u->elem<<std::endl;
    u->next = v;                // link u in between v
    u->prev = v->prev;              // ...and v->prev
    v->prev->next = u;              // do this first......
    v->prev = u;                    // then this.
}
```